# Yahoo Finance Quarterly Data Not Yet Updated. How long does it take for this to go into effect?

Tags: yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

It's January 6th. A lot of companies have already released their annual reports for the year end, but yahoo finance has not updated them. For example [this stock](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/b/financials?p=b) has had its earnings report, but the site hasn't posted the quarterly income statement for 12/30/2021. (after clicking the link, select "Income Statement" then "Quarterly" to see what I say is missing)

Anyone have a clue why this is the case and how long it takes yahoo finance to post the recent quarterly earnings on its site?

Answer (score 0):

Barnes Group released 4th quarter 2021 earnings (12/31/2021) on February 18, 2022.  All publicly traded (yes, all) companies have a roughly 30-60 lag between a quarter end and reporting.  Yahoo can't report before a company does, although we'd all make a lot of money if we could subscribe to that service.